Loading model error. How can I fix this error?
I am trying to build a rock paper scissor detection program. When I am trying to load my saved model from local directory using the load_model function from tf.keras.models I  am encountering this error. How can I modify my code to use my pre-saved model? Please help me; I am a beginner-level programmer.

Error loading model: Layer "dense" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 1024), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_175>, <KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 1024), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_176>]

Code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

# Mapping of class indices to labels

CLASS_MAP = {
    0: 'rock',
    1: 'paper',
    2: 'scissor'
}

# Load the model once

try:
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('D:\\practice_CV22\\new_mobilenet_model.h5')
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error loading model: {str(e)}")
    exit()

def detection_fn(image_batch):
    predictions = model.predict_on_batch(image_batch).flatten()
    class_id = np.argmax(predictions)
    label = CLASS_MAP\[class_id\]
    confidence = predictions\[class_id\]
    return label, confidence

def preprocess_frame(frame, img_size=224):
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (img_size, img_size))
    frame = image.img_to_array(frame)
    frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
    frame = frame / 255.0
    return frame

# Initialize webcam

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open webcam.")
    exit()

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Preprocess the frame
    processed_frame = preprocess_frame(frame)
    
    # Detect objects
    label, confidence = detection_fn(processed_frame)
    
    # Draw the label on the frame
    cv2.putText(frame, f"{label}: {confidence:.2f}", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
   


    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('Webcam Object Detection', frame)
    
    # Break the loop on 'q' key press
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video capture object and close all OpenCV windows

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Hey, looks like the code you pasted in didn't format right with spacing. try copy-pasting again or see here for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

How did you save this model? Are you using different versions of the libraries in the training task?
